# Java - paintComponent won't show drawings on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've gotten stuck trying to draw on a `JPanel`. I've learned how to create a `JFrame`, a `JPanel`, add event handlers, do the same in applets, and some other basic GUI development. But everytime I try to draw on a `JPanel` using the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` or `paint(Graphics g)` methods, nothing shows up. Buttons, as well as other `JComponents`, show up just fine. But `g.drawString`, `g.drawRect`, etc result in a blank `JFrame` window.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game().game();
    }

    JPanel panel;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button;

    public void game() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Ok");
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(button);

        button2 = new JButton("Cancel");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("hi",100,100);
        g.fillRect(100,50,200,300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `JPanel` you're adding to your `JFrame` is a plain vanilla `JPanel`, not an instance of `Game`, your custom class that contains the `paintComponent()` method. YOu need to change that one line to

```
JPanel panel = new Game();
```

and you should see a difference immediately!

The instance of `Game` you create in `main()` isn't being used for anything, other than calling the `game()` method. You could use it, if you wanted, by doing this instead:

```
JPanel panel = this;
```

and then proceeding as before.

Comment: Thank you so much Ernest! It worked! But I just don't understand what instance of a class means. Can you also just explain the "JPanel panel = new Game();"? Thanks again for your time and effort!